# Weird error while installing OSPD (OpenVAS)

Tags: python-3.x, openvas

Im trying to compile all necesary modules in order to setup an **OpenVAS** local server, when I try to install OSPD module I get an error. I have already read the read info at their [github page](https://github.com/greenbone/ospd/)  and installed all necesary packages, but I keep getting the same error when I try:

```
root@debian-server:/home/openvas/ospd-master# python3 setup.py install
..........................................................
Copying ospd-21.10.0.dev1-py3.7.egg to /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
ospd 21.10.0.dev1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ospd-21.10.0.dev1-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for ospd==21.10.0.dev1
Searching for deprecated
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/deprecated/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/deprecated/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'deprecated' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.org/simple/: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or working download links found for deprecated
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('deprecated')
```

What do I need to do for be able to install it (I dont wanna install it trough `pip`)

Note: I only copy the error section in order to keep clean this page...

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparantly was a self mistake due to a missconfiguration on proxy enviromentals varibles. Apparently `pip` works over https and I had a missconfiguration